# UITableView numberOfRowsInSection - showing complete/incomplete tasks

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm fairly new to the world of Swift and iOS and I'm creating a to-do list application. I have detail view that shows a list name and its tasks. My goal is to show the tasks in two separate sections, one for incomplete task and another for completed tasks.

In numberOfRowsInSection, if I use:

```
return list.tasks.count
```

I get this:

[image]

In my numberOfSectionsInTableView method I return 2 and as you can see in the image I am returning the tasks to both sections. It's obvious to me why, but I can't figure out how to get this right.

In list.task.count "task" is a class that has a property "var isComplete: Bool = false" that I was hoping to use to separate the complete/incomplete tasks here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show  "list" model . how you designed.

Comment: This is what I changed it to. As you can see I am now using a separate array for complete and incomplete tasks.

`class List: NSObject {
    var name = ""
    // var tasks = [Task]()
    var completeTask = [Task]()
    var incompleteTask = [Task]()
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to have to different arrays. One for complete tasks and one for incomplete tasks, then you can check the section of the Table View to know how many rows to return.

In numberOfRows:

```
if section == 0 {
    return completedTasks.count
} else {
    return incompleteTasks.count
}
```

This will also let you check in the cellForRowAtIndexPath the section and you won't need to mess around with remembering where in the array your complete/incomplete tasks are up to:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    cell.task = completedTasks[indexPath.row]
} else {
    cell.task = incompleteTask[indexPath.row]
}
```

Update:

To address this issue in the comments:

```
if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? TaskDetailViewController {
    let selectedRow = tableViewTasks.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row { 
        // let incompleteTask = list.incompleteTask[selectedRow] 
        // let completeTask = list.completeTask[selectedRow] 
        // destination.task = list.tasks[selectedRow] 
    }
}
```

You should be checking if the tableViewTasks.indexPathForSelectedRow exists, not if the row exists so change:

```
let selectedRow = tableViewTasks.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
```

to

```
if let selectedIndexPath = tableViewTasks.indexPathForSelectedRow {
```

then check the section to see which array you want and the row to see which index you want :

```
if selectedIndexPath.section == 0 {
    destination.task = list.completedTasks[selectedIndexPath.row]
} else {
    destination.task = list.incompleteTasks[selectedIndexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sam. Where are you suggesting I create the different arrays? In the List class? I did this and it works great for display the data, but now accessing the view from prepareForSegue is where I'm having issue.

Comment: Yeah, in the list class works fine. Could you elaborate more on your issue with prepareForSegue or if it is unrelated you can post another question

Comment: This is what prepareForSegue looks like:

`if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? TaskDetailViewController, let selectedRow = tableViewTasks.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            {
                // let incompleteTask = list.incompleteTask[selectedRow]
                // let completeTask = list.completeTask[selectedRow]
                // destination.task = list.tasks[selectedRow]
            }`

Comment: Ah, again here you need to check the section. So instead of indexPathForSelectedRow?.row you should just check indexPathForSelectedRow. From here you could check the section as selectedRow.section and get the index as selectedRow.row (may want to change naming convention)

Comment: I have edited my original post to show this in more detail

Comment: I saw and now it makes perfect sense. Thank you very much time and for going into detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make the assumption that you have two tables, one for completed tasks and one for incomplete tasks. What you need to be doing is probably something similar to this:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return list.tasks.count
        } else {
            return lists.completedTasks.count
        }
    }
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should set up the cells with the relevant info. You can get the section and row from the indexPath variable in that function and use that information to set up the cell as needed.

Comment: No, I only have one table and multiple sections. I tried changing the properties in my List class from

`var tasks = [Task]()`

to:
`// var tasks = [Task]()`
`var completeTask = [Task]()`
`var incompleteTask = [Task]()`

but this causes me further issues when trying to access this task later in my task detail view.

Answer (score 0):

In your data source method `tableView(_: numberOfRowsInSection:)` you should return a different value depending on the section index; e.g.:

```
if section == 0 {

    return activeTasks.count
}
else if section == 1 {

    return completedTasks.count
}
else {

    return 0 // Error - should never happen
}
```

(Assumes you keep the completed tasks and the non-completed tasks in two separate arrays)